# Besides the Agents what else was there actively looking for people in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

While giving my answer to another question I realized that Tank and Dozer are on watch reading the Matrix from the Nebuchadnezzar or someone else in the crew is always watching. Other than the Agents though what are they watching out for? Especially when plugged into the Matrix.

Comment: Pure speculation: (a) potential people to rescue (b) red dresses :)

Comment: Technically you only have to watch out for a red dress because an Agent is behind you. Simple solution every time you see an attractive woman in a red dress shot behind you and keep watching.

Comment: They can be watching out for messages/contact from other people in the matrix.  I.e. the Oracle, other ships crews etc.

Comment: It seems like there is a constant threat of detection though. I'm curious as to if there is anything other than the Agents which for the most part don't pop up all the time unless you're Neo or with him.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of other things that operators would be watching for:

- [**Programs**](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Program): sentient machines that appear as human in the matrix and are responsible for performing various maintenance roles. Agents are merely a subset of these programs. Other examples are [Rama Kandra](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Rama_Kandra) (a power plant systems manager for recycling operations) and his wife [Kamala](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Kamala) (an interactive software programmer). Operators would want to look out for these programs because they could still pose a direct or indirect threat to [redpills](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Redpills) if they discover who they are or what they're doing.
- [**Exiles**](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Exiles): programs that are obsolete, have no purpose, or no longer function properly, but who refuse to return to [the Source](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Source). These rogue programs are no longer working with the machines, but can be a danger in and of themselves and must be watched out for. Many appear as human, such as [the Merovingian](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Merovingian), his wife [Persephone](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Persephone), [the Trainman](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trainman), [the Keymaker](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Keymaker), and [Sati](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Sati). Others have the appearance or characteristics of paranormal creatures, such as [the Twins](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Twins) (ghosts), [Seraph](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph) (a wingless angel), and two of the Merovingian's thugs [Cain](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Cain) (a vampire) and [Abel](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Abel) (a werewolf).
- **[Déjà vus](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/De%27ja_vu) (or generally any glitches)**: A déjà vu is an indicator that the code of the Matrix has been altered. In the scene in the Lafayette Hotel where Neo sees a black cat walk by twice, the Matrix is changed to seal off the hotel's exits. It appears that this change is simultaneously discovered both by [Mouse](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mouse) (in the Matrix) and [Tank](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Tank) (outside the Matrix), suggesting that glitches like a déjà vu can still be noticed by operators.

Comment: Since this is a highly supported answer and no one else has bothered to answer it I'm going to award you the bounty and accept the answer. I was hoping for a few more answers. I like yours and it contains a lot of information but I really feel there must be something more that the Operators must be watching for.

Comment: They also watch humans, their own and others (possible recruits or just [interesting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vAnuBtyEYE)).